# Why the WGS84 in Trimble Business Center software is different than real?

Tags: coordinate-system

Why is the WGS84 in Trimble Business Center software different than another software than Leica Infinity or the public WGS84?

In the picture, the flattening(1/f) is 298.25722293287 in TBCv3.5 software. But the public WGS84, the flattening(1/f) is 298.257223563.

It will have error 1cm when switched from Lat, Long, Heigh to X, Y, Z when using the TBC software

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Propably only Trimble knows. However, the difference in the two flattening values is only 0.63 millimeters. I wonder how it can make 1 cm difference in x, y, and z values. Compare with the difference in flattening of WGS 84 and GRS 80 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Geodetic_System#WGS84 which should give a difference of 0.105 mm.

I am quite sure that you can just neglect the millimeter scale differences in flattening, most probably your GPS equipment is introducing much bigger errors in any case.

Comment: It's just the difference from calculating b from a and f vs f calculating from a and b.